# Trying to install an openVPN GUI messed up sudoers

Tags: openvpn

I installed openVPN successfully but I would like to get remote desktop access with it, as is the case with openVPN in Windows. I found this GUI here http://sourceforge.net/projects/sogfl/ and installed it and everything, but I realized that it has actually messed up my `/etc/sudoers` file. It has added a line like this:

```
%sogfl: ALL=(root) NOPASSWORD : openvpn
```

(not sure of the exact syntax because I can't open the file right now because sudo isn't working).

Is there any way I can fix this? I noticed that `/etc/group`, my username is listed after sudo and admin, but not root (which is blank).

Any fixes? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably restore your sudoers file by typing `pkexec visudo` in a shell.

Comment: Should I delete the line though? I still want to be able to use sogfl.

Comment: If that line breaks your sudoers file? You choose.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? Now that you have `sudo visudo` back, you should be able to edit sudoers in such a way that it does not break (that's what `visudo` is for).