# How do I perform a backup of sudoers file?

Tags: backup, sudo, restore

After reading the following two posts:

[Trying to install an openVPN GUI messed up sudoers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264474/trying-to-install-an-openvpn-gui-messed-up-sudoers)

[Standards accounts are able to get root access using sudo without password request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316256/standards-accounts-are-able-to-get-root-access-using-sudo-without-password-reque/316323#316323)

I would like to learn how to perform a backup of /etc/sudoers file so that I can restore it in the event of a mess-up after installing a non-Ubuntu-package-ready software.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.backup
```

To restore:

```
sudo rm -rfv /etc/sudoers && sudo mv /etc/sudoers.backup /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: +1 can't believe you are first to answer in 6 years. There is also the directory `/etc/sudoers.d` to backup.

Answer (score 0):

If `/etc/sudoers` is going to be a problem you probably should just keep all of /etc in version control since they're just some text files. Check this out:

- [Is there an application to manage config files in the /etc folder with version control software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279140/is-there-an-application-to-manage-config-files-in-the-etc-folder-with-version-c/279171#279171)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am still clueless after reading the page referenced by your URL. I do not know what "version control" and "git" mean. I am new to Ubuntu and yes, I am not an IT guy. I just wish to have a simple method of backing up /etc/sudoers file.